# What happens when invalidateOptionsMenu() is called in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-menu

I am very keen to know what happens when an call to `invalidateOptionsMenu()` is made. Does it redraws the whole actionbar or just place a call to `onCreateOptionsMenu()` which follows with `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. As per android source code it declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The `onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)` method will be called the next time it needs to be displayed. I have certain points that needs clarification:

- Does it affects the ActionBar tabs in any way?
- Does it affects the    viewpager inside the layout of activity?
- Does it impacts the    fragments associated with actionbar tabs?

Answer (score 4):

It declares that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) method will be called the next time it needs
to be displayed.

> Does it affects the ActionBar tabs in any way?

It will redraw them.

> Does it affects the viewpager inside the layout of activity?

It does not.

> Does it impacts the fragments associated with actionbar tabs?

It does not

Comment: Hi @Smittey you said InvalidateOptionMenu() will create the ActioBar Tabs. I am just curious to know the piece of code that performs that you know just to ensure that it is really happening and how i can avoid this to happen. Because due to this call Fragments associated with tabs are getting destroyed on S3.

Comment: Update: I have identified the reason for fragments disappearing is calling invalidate options menu from non UI thread